# Can not access controller.RestController for maven build

Tags: spring, spring-restcontroller

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.0:compile (default-compile) on project aragon-external: Compilation failure
[ERROR] /C:/Applications/aragonweb/aragon-external/src/main/java/com/yax/aragon/external/controller/AccountController.java:[25,2] cannot access com.yax.aragon.external.controller.RestController
```

this is the error.

```
AccountController
```

path is:

```
com.yax.aragon.external.controller;
```

Main class has those:

```
@EnableScheduling
@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan("com.yax.aragon.external")
public class AragonConsoleApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {
```

but still has same error. why can not see `restcontroller`?

Comment: Have you created a class `RestController`?And what have you annotated the `AccountController` class with?

Answer (score 2):

Error clearly says `Compilation failure`, add following import statement in your class `AccountController`, & it will work

```
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
```